# Нужно ли (можно ли) заключить "привет" в кавычки в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, авторская-пунктуация

Нужно ли (можно ли) заключить слово "привет" в кавычки, когда пишешь "мой теплый **привет** из холодного Омска"? Под словом "привет" имеется в виду само письмо, которое посылаю

Answer (score 2):

Из предметного указателя к "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> Употребление кавычек
>
> при прямой речи, расположенной в строку (в подбор) § 133, п. 1; § 134–137
>
> при выделении цитат § 140–148
>
> при выделении чужих слов в авторском тексте § 148
>
> при выделении необычно или особо употребляемых   слов
> (специальных, профессиональных принадлежащих узкому кругу обращающихся) § 150
>
> при выделении иностилевых слов (не соответствующих общему тону изложения) § 151
>
> при выделении иронически звучащих слов § 151
>
> при выделении слов, особо значимых для автора § 152
>
> при выделении необычно употребленных грамматических форм § 153

Слово `привет` в вашем конкретном случае является существительным, используемым, насколько я могу судить (без контекста фразы), искренне и в весьма прямом смысле — значит, кавычки не нужны.

Если ваш стиль плохо сочетается со словом `привет`, то можно воспользоваться:

> §151. Кавычками выделяются **иностилевые слова**, подчеркивается ироническое значение слова, дается указание на двойной смысл слова или смысл, известный лишь тому, кому адресованы слова

С куда более значительным трудом можно притянуть:

> §152. Кавычками выделяются слова, употребляемые в особом, часто условном значении

Это в том случае, если вы считаете, что слово `привет` не может применяться для обозначения вашего письма. На мой взгляд, это применимо, только если ваше письмо является чем-то кроме дружественного сообщения (например, официальный запрос или повестку сложно назвать "приветом", разве что в ироничном смысле).

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.